# Delete Array from Multidimensional array stored in local storage using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

This is my multidimentional array:

```
[
    {"leads":"Akhil","email":"anand@patel.com","phone":"9999-999-999","referance":"ByReferance","nameref":"Anand","preftime":"Afteroon"},
    {"leads":"Anand","email":"a@a.com","phone":"9998789333","referance":"email","nameref":"AAA","preftime":"Afteroon"}
]
```

I want to delete this array from the Multidimensional array, with OnClick event of button

`{"leads":"Akhil","email":"anand@patel.com","phone":"9999-999-999","referance":"ByReferance","nameref":"Anand","preftime":"Afteroon"}`

,How it is possible?

Comment: use splice function to delete . array.splice(Index,1);

Comment: you want to find out the item in array based on name?

Answer (score 1):

suppose this is the value obtained from `localstorage.getItem("contacts");`

```
var value = JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem("contacts"));
```

for the sake of this example

```
var value = [{"leads":"Akhil","email":"anand@patel.com","phone":"9999-999-999","referance":"ByReferance","nameref":"Anand","preftime":"Afteroon"},{"leads":"Anand","email":"a@a.com","phone":"9998789333","referance":"email","nameref":"AAA","preftime":"Afteroon"}];
```

Assuming you want to delete an item based on the `leads name`, you need to loop and find out the required index

```
var index = -1;
for ( var counter = 0; counter < value.length; counter++)
{
   if ( value[ counter ].leads == "Akhil" )
   {
      index = counter;
      break;
   }
}
```

all you need to do is remove first item from the value array

```
value.splice(0,1); // index = 1
```

and set the value back to localstorage

```
localstorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(value));
```